# Complex Linq Query find sum of field for n items in another collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have some sample data and am trying to determine the 5 "most sold products" and then trying to find how many of each of these products was purchased by the client with the ID#1
in June 2013.

I have the following data structures:

```
public class MonthlyHistoric
{

  public int StoreCode { get; set; }
  public int Month { get; set; }
  public int Year { get; set; }
  public int NumberOfSales { get; set; }
  public int ItemCode { get; set; }

}

public class Recipt
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime SaleDate { get; set; }
  public int CustomerID {get;set;}
}

public class ReciptDetails
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int IdRecipt { get; set; }
  public int ItemCode { get; set; }
  public int AmountSold { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following test data:

```
List<MonthlyHistoric> Historic = new List<MonthlyHistoric> { 
  new MonthlyHistoric() {ItemCode= 101, Month=6, NumberOfSales=20,StoreCode=7,Year= 2013 },
  new MonthlyHistoric() {ItemCode= 102, Month=6, NumberOfSales=100,StoreCode=7,Year= 2013 },
  new MonthlyHistoric() {ItemCode= 103, Month=6, NumberOfSales=30,StoreCode=7,Year= 2013 },
  new MonthlyHistoric() {ItemCode= 105, Month=6, NumberOfSales=20,StoreCode=3,Year= 2013 }};

List<Recipt> Recipts = new List<Recipt> { 
  new Recipt() { Id = 1, SaleDate = new DateTime(2013, 6, 02), CustomerID =1 },
  new Recipt() { Id = 2, SaleDate = new DateTime(2013, 7, 01), CustomerID =1 },
  new Recipt() { Id = 3, SaleDate = new DateTime(2013, 6, 04), CustomerID =2 },
  new Recipt() { Id = 4, SaleDate = new DateTime(2013, 5, 14), CustomerID =1 },
  new Recipt() { Id = 5, SaleDate = new DateTime(2013, 6, 16), CustomerID =2 },
  new Recipt() { Id = 6, SaleDate = new DateTime(2013, 6, 12), CustomerID =1 }};

List<ReciptDetails> Details = new List<ReciptDetails> { 
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 200, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 1, ItemCode = 101 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 234, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 1, ItemCode = 101 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 2050, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 2, ItemCode = 101 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 20340, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 2, ItemCode = 102 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 2300, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 3, ItemCode = 102 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 2200, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 3, ItemCode = 103 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 200, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 4, ItemCode = 101 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 10, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 5, ItemCode = 101 },
   new ReciptDetails() { AmountSold = 2400, Id = 1, IdRecipt = 6, ItemCode = 101 }};
```

with the following expression i can obtain the top 5 products sold by a store (#7 in this example) in the 6th month of 2013

```
Historic.Where (x => x.StoreCode == 7 && x.Year == 2013 && x.Month== 6).OrderBy (x =>x.NumberOfSales ).Take(5)
```

Now for each one of these 5 elements I need find out how many items client number 1 has bought during the 6th month of 2013. I would have to determine what recipients were issued in June and then check if the associated details include one of the top 5 items.

I am trying do this doing a single Linq Expression. But multiple expressions are an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a second LINQ expression. I also rewrote your one long line to a (IMHO) more readable query syntax.

```
var topItems = (from h in Historic
                where h.StoreCode == 7 && h.Year == 2013 && h.Month == 6
                orderby h.NumberOfSales
                select h.ItemCode).Take(5).ToList();
var sum =
   (from r in Recipts
    where r.CustomerID == 1 && r.SaleDate.Year == 2013 && r.SaleDate.Month == 6
    join d in Details on r.Id equals d.IdRecipt
    where topItems.Contains(d.ItemCode)
    select d.AmountSold).Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum); // 2834
```

Comment: But the crowds where chanting for one line!

Comment: You can make the query syntax on one line, if you like. I think it'll be about as long as the method syntax, but it's around 350 characters, so it'd be around a 350-character line. That's too long for my tastes.